# Problem with chosing item from array list

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a problem when I try to make the custom select drop-down list, well, when I use an array list in the map() everything goes fine, but when I push enter an item in the input field is shown like [object Object],
I tried almost every possible parse...

Here is my drop-down list code sample.

```
 const handleChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  }

    
const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
        if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
          event.preventDefault();
          const nextOption = highlightedOption + 1;
          if (nextOption < statusList.length) {
            setHighlightedOption(nextOption);
          }
        } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
          event.preventDefault();
          const prevOption = highlightedOption - 1;
          if (prevOption >= 0) {
            setHighlightedOption(prevOption);
          }
        } else if (event.key === 'Enter' && highlightedOption !== -1) {
          setSelectedOption(statusList[highlightedOption]);
          setShowList(false)
        }
      }
```

This is my input and div map() list.

```
<input className={`${classes.input} ${statusIsValid&&selectedOption===''  ? classes.border : ''} ${statusIsValid&&selectedOption===null  ? classes.border : ''}`}
        type="text"
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={handleChange}
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        onClick={showListFunc}
        placeholder="Odjel"
        ref={input1Ref}
      />
       {showList && <div className={classes.options}>
        {statusList.map((option, index) => (
          <div
            key={Math.random()}
            style={{ backgroundColor: index === highlightedOption ? 'lightgray' : 'white' }}
          >
            {option.naziv}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>}
```

And when I try to console log my current statusList I get this:

[image: Console.log() from browser]

My full code under [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-leftpad-0v8x81?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Can you provide a online editor like codesandbox to show the problem?

Comment: Of course, this is codesandbox link: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-leftpad-0v8x81?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I post a answer and new link, Is that result you want lol, Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated a new code link. https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-fire-hmrqyf?file=/src/App.js:930-991

And I use fake data to try, Only different is here:

```
... 
else if (event.key === "Enter" && highlightedOption !== -1) {
      setSelectedOption(statusList[highlightedOption].opis);
      setShowList(false);
    }
...
```